# Working in UTC time in webclient(angular), how to post it unmodified to web-api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a web app where the users work in UTC. Client uses angularjs $http.
That is if they set the time in GUI to 8:00 they expect that, whatever action is to be taken, will be executed at 8:00 UTC time.

Problem is, when i post this date to asp.net web API it correctly assumes that the time is local time(as always in JS), which causes  somewhere in the serialization/de-serialization the date is converted to UTC time. In my case when i work in UTC+1, this will pull the time back by one hour, so the value received in my API controller is 7:00.

How can i solve this in a neat way? I basically don't want serialization to touch the value of the datetime..

Datetime is posted in this format:

```
2014-02-14T18:24:00.619Z
```

But in this case, what i had in my input is

```
2014-02-14T19:24:00.619Z
```

So seems client side serialization is the issue.

Comment: The "cleanest" solution would be to make sure everything that handles dates/time does so with the same offset. I'd suggest having JS convert the date to UTC, and make sure the server interprets it as such.

Comment: You can send date as timestamp -> +(new Date()) and convert it to server local time on backend. This should unify time across clients and backend machines in different timezones. If you want to stick to UTC time you can send date as (new Date()).toUTCString()

Comment: What format are you sending the date in? Web Api's JSON formatter by default (at least in Web API v2) will recognize ISO 8601 formats and can deserialize the date as UTC, [provided you indicate in the date string it is UTC by using the `Z` marker at the end of the string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC).

Comment: I will look into how i send it. I just use angular defaults right now.